# Divide all columns by one, line by line, printing NA where division by 0

Tags: awk

I have a tab delim file

```
1A      865     508     512    0       2       0       0
1B      0       0       0      0       0       0       1
```

I need to divide every col from `$3` on by `$2` and multiply the resulting by 100 line by line, printing NA where division by 0.

So that I have

```
1A  865 58.73  59.19 0.00  0.23  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
1B  0   NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

I tried

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR>1 {for(i=3;i<=NR;i++) $i={print $0"\t"($2?$i/$2*100:"NaN")1}'
```

but I get `"unexpected newline or end of string"`

Comment: Seeing you write `$i={print $0"\t"($2?$i/$2*100:"NaN")1}` is kinda worrying since it's so far away from correct, or even valid, awk syntax and you've asked 53 questions over the last 5 years, many of them about awk. That is trying to set the value of each field to the output of printing the current record concatenated with the result of arithmetic and then a 1 concatenated on the end. You must've come across awk scripts that change the value of a field before now (or could find many with a quick google or look through the archives here). Was it just a "need more coffee" moment?

Comment: And also you're printing `NaN` when you wanted to print `NA` and looping to `NR` which is the current record number instead of `NF` which is the number of fields. I'm sure I've seen you post far more reasonable scripts in previous questions.

Comment: I'm good. No need to worry! Just, my learning trajectory is bumpy rather than a constantly ascending path, plus happily awk is not the only thing I've been learning these past 5 years. Appreciate the help from you from the start though! I'll try to be more thoughtful in my many to come questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following based on your shown samples only. Basically you need to make 2 major changes here, 1st your loop should run till value of `NF` NOT `NR`, 2nd- you are using print while assigning current field's value which we don't want to do. I have written this on mobile so haven't tested it yet but should work I believe.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="\t"
}
FNR>1{
  for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){
    $i=($2?($i/$2)*100:"NaN")
  }
}
1' Input_file
```

Comment: @MadzaFarias-Virgens, your welcome, cheers and happy learning.